# React component doesn't change parent's state

Tags: reactjs, blockly

In component `BlocklyDrawer` i'm trying to change the `code` state of the parent component. I do it in the `onChange()` event, calling the method of the parent component `handleCodex`:

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code : "xxx",
    }; 
       this.handleCodex = 
        this.handleCodex.bind(this);
  }

handleCodex(codex){      
  this.setState = ({
      code: codex,
    });
}


<BlocklyDrawer
      tools={[INICIAR, MOVER, ATACAR]}
      language = {Blockly.Javascript}
      onChange={(code, workspace) => {                       
        this.handleCodex(code);
      }}
      appearance={
        {
          categories: {
            Agente: {
              colour: '160'
            },
          },
        }
      }
    >
```

Although the method `handleCodex` is executed, the `code` state does not change.

Comment: Can you also include the code from your BlocklyDrawer component?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/xvicmanx/react-blockly-drawer/blob/master/src/BlocklyDrawer.js

Comment: you're _assigning_ to `this.setState` rather than _calling_ it in `handleCodex`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do not understand. How should I invoke the handleCode method from onChange?

Answer (score 1):

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code : "xxx",
    }; 
       this.handleCodex = 
        this.handleCodex.bind(this);
  }

handleCodex(codex){      
  this.setState({
      code: codex,
    });  // this.setState is like a function call. Not a assignment statement.
}


<BlocklyDrawer
      tools={[INICIAR, MOVER, ATACAR]}
      language = {Blockly.Javascript}
      onChange={(code, workspace) => {                       
        this.handleCodex(code);
      }}
      appearance={
        {
          categories: {
            Agente: {
              colour: '160'
            },
          },
        }
      }
    >
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that does not help me.